# Html.DisplayForModel() doesnot bind URL as HyperLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view

I am learning Entity Framework in MVC from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f4P8U1a2TI

I am displaying a URL to View ...from DB Column the URL Value is 'http://www.pragimtech.com/' ... I am using Html.DisplayForModel() to Bind Data . But when URL Display as plain Text .. Not as HyperLink...

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
          //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {   
            SampleDbContext db = new SampleDbContext();
            Employee emp= db.Employees.Single(x=>x.Id==id);
            return View(emp);
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Employee

<div style="font-family: Arial">
@Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

What is missing?

Comment: You could do something like this: <a href="@Model.URL">text</a>

Comment: Html.DisplayNameFor() is binding all properties ... so dont wanna bind url seperately

Answer (score 0):

ok ,Got It ...
Need to put [DataType(DataType.Url)] attribute on
On the URL prperty

like

```
public class EmployeeMetaData
{

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string PersonalWebSite { get; set; }
}
```